# Benefits when changing from JRun 4.0 to Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, jrun

We are running one single instance **ColdFusion 9.0.1 Enterprise on JRun 4.0** - As I just read CF 10 will **replace JRun with Tomcat**. What are the **main benefits** I'm gaining by switching over to Tomcat?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JRun is a full-featured Java EE platform, similar to WebSphere, while Tomcat is simply a Servlet container. However, JRun hasn't had any new development since around 2007. It's essentially a dead product. Tomcat on the other hand, is community based and constantly under development. If you need more than what Tomcat offers, you can always add JBoss into the mix.

There's nothing stopping you from running CF 9 on Tomcat now, it's just that certain CF Admin functions are geared towards configuring JRun. I'm sure the CF10 Admin will be geared towards Tomcat when it arrives.

Comment: Just to clarify, ColdFusion Zeus (10?) will not have jRun. It will be running on Tomcat.

Answer (score 10):

Additional benefits to add to what iKnowKungFoo stated:

- It's faster than JRun
- It uses less memory than JRun
- Starts faster than JRun (I had 4 instances of CF9 deployed as wars starting in 14 seconds)
- Improved support for Java EE specs (Servlet Spec 3.0 for example)

Here are some links with great info:

[Running multiple CFML Engines on Apache Tomcat with Matt Woodward](http://experts.na3.acrobat.com/p13033917/) (Video)

[Configuring ColdFusion applications on Tomcat with Apache web server by Dan Skaggs](http://www.tntechnohermit.com/2009/02/25/configuring-coldfusion-applications-on-tomcat-with-apache-web-server/) (Blog Post)

Comment: Do you have some links or post related to Coldfusion under Tomcat ?
I'm realy interested de know how it work!